# Found GPG old keys on keyserver but accounts long since gone - cleanup?

Tags: gnupg

So I went to MIT's keyserver and discovered a few old public keys were there after dong a search. I don't have any of these keys anymore. Is it possible to have the public keys removed from the system?  They've likely not been used in years.

Comment: Have what remove exactly?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Are you asking how to get MIT's keyserver cleaned up, or how to remove obsolete keys from your own system?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot *delete* keys from the key server network, also have a look at my answer on [How long do keys stay on keyservers?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67633/how-long-do-keys-stay-on-keyservers/67636#67636) in the Security Stack Exchange for the reasons.

**If you still have access to the private keys, *revoke* them instead.** Revoking means marking a key as not used any more. It will not show up any more for others or will be marked as revoked. Doing so is as easy as opening the edit key menu through `gpg --edit-key [key-id]` and in there, running `revkey`. [Import and upload the resulting revocation certificate.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523250/how-do-i-revoke-a-pgp-key-on-a-server/523361#523361) The whole process is also possible through the graphical user interface, but differs from client to client.

**If you have no access any more, bad luck.** For some perspective, read [How to revoke old OpenPGP keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597750/how-to-revoke-old-openpgp-keys/597802#597802).